# Missing component on the Usb to RS485 converter

Tags: pcb, usb, rs485

I have a Usb to RS485 converter that was dead on arrival. I opened it up to see if I could fix it to find out that it was missing a component on the top left corner. This is a very common converter. Can someone who has the same device tell me what the missing component is?

Thank you!

[image: IMG]
[image: Usb to RS485]

Comment: Looks like a termination resistir, which would be 120 ohm. If you use short cables, should be fine this way. Still the question is, how do you know it's dead? Rs485 is a little tricky because you have to enable transmission.

Comment: When I plug it in a linux machine, nothing shows up under dmesg. Same for windows under device manager. I think i will wait until tomorrow and try the 120 ohm resistor. Thank you

Comment: No, no. It doesn't make sense. You have a usb problem, not Rs485. So it's on the other side of the board.

Comment: My guess is you should throw this garbage away and buy a new one. Sorry about that...

Comment: This is an off-topic "repair in the absence of engineering detail" question.  It's not at all clear that the unpopulated part is "missing" rather than intentionally unpopulated.  To understand which, you'd need to analyze the circuit, something that should not be that difficult given that the main IC data sheet is probably available, and the output connections presumably known.  You've also failed to specify how you've determined that it is "dead" - if that resistor is what most are speculating, **it would not cause the claimed problem**.

Comment: Failed by who's standards? When you plug in a usb converter to linux it does show up under debug messages. This device doesn't. If my determination doesn't satisfy you, you don't have to participate.

Comment: Failed by the standards of the website you posted this question to.. Repair questions must involve specific troubleshooting steps, not determination alone. A non-populated component doesn't necessarily indicate a fault, as other comments have posted. I've had CH340 devices not working before and it was purely a driver problem, for example..

Comment: Not working and dead are 2 different things. A non-dead device should have some presence in the logs even without drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Looks like it is missing a resistor with the marking 121 on it (120Ω)

There must be one at each end of the buss. So if this is just point to point, then it may be added externally to the screw terminals. (kudos to GK for the nudge)

I would use a logic probe, scope or DMM on the MAX chip pin 1,2,6,7 and check status. If RE is low then RO = voltage(Pin 7-pin 6) "1"=+ve, "0"=-ve

Comment: Which makes sense, because the user should terminate where he wants to.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the max485 datasheet and look at the typical application schematic.  Then trace out and compare the board you have to it. Most likely is a resistor or cap.

Then again, it might not be missing. Unpopulated components are common.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those stupid crappy cheap USB-RS485 modules from China that do not properly terminate the output nor do they properly enable the fake RS485 driver. It might work okay on a clear day with a very short cable, but what you have there is a bit of a steaming pile of something.

The main chip is a CH340G, which is a standard Chinese-origin USB-Serial chip. This chip should have kernel support by any recent version of Linux. If it's not enumerating then there's something likely wrong with the USB chip, the crystal or the connector.

It's definitely not the resistor position you point out, and adding a 120\$\Omega\$ resistor there won't help and may make things worse. You will find that they do not actually drive the bus actively in one direction and depend on resistors to the supply to passively drive the bus. The drive impedance is thus both asymmetrical and incorrect.

You can try inspecting it for bad connections and replacing the crystal if you feel like it. In particular, **wiggle the connector** while looking at the SMT pins (**preferably under a magnifier in good light**) and see if one of the connections is broken- since that's a likely path for damage.